# Storing values into the database from a deserialized variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to store the values of a deserialized object in the database. My deserialized object is according to the image I uploaded.

I tried to implement `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` interfaces so that I can make my class foreach accessible.

```
public class Result:IEnumerable,IEnumerator
```

But then there is exception coming with my deserialization process.

[image]

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: can not deserealize json string into the class object..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the `Result.data` property which is a collection:

```
Result soap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(ser);
foreach (var item in soap.data)
{
    ... do something with each element of the data collection
}
```

Comment: I specified in my question that when I make my class capable of using foreach, then I get exception

Comment: @aviral, why do you need to make your class capable of foreach? Simply use its `data` property to loop through.

Comment: its giving error because my class doesnt implement IEnumerable interface

Comment: @aviral, that's because you are doing `foreach (var item in soap)` whereas you should do `foreach (var item in soap.data)` as explained in my answer.

Comment: okayy its working thanks for your patience..:) still in learning phase.

Comment: I accepted your answer..there are no issues now..might have some more doubts ..will keep posting..:)